# Cannot login to Kali Linux when ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: ethernet, login, kali-linux

I am Using Asus K550V in dual-boot mode - Kali Linux and Windows 10. On Windows 10 I have no issues with network connections - both Wi-Fi and ethernet are working correctly.

On Kali however, only Wi-Fi is working correctly (obtaining and maintaining address information via DHCP). When ethernet cable is plugged in and I boot into Kali I enter a login loop - just like described in post [Can't login in Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/987969/cant-login-in-kali-linux?newreg=fa1466036105465a96d7b942afbf3445). I have tried all answers from this post (except resetting preferences) without success. Also, when Kali is running and I plug the cable, after several "Activation connection failed" messages, I am logged off and cannot login again. I thought it is something related to the DHCP settings but when changing to static configuration, the issue remains the same.

Regardless of whether cable is plugged or not, I get a `FAILED` message during boot (not sure if it is related):

```
systemctl status vmware-USBArbitrator.service 
● vmware-USBArbitrator.service - LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-09-02 17:38:08 EEST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 598 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 02 17:38:08 MyKali systemd[1]: Starting LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator....
Sep 02 17:38:08 MyKali vmware-USBArbitrator[598]: [11B blob data]
Sep 02 17:38:08 MyKali systemd[1]: vmware-USBArbitrator.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 02 17:38:08 MyKali systemd[1]: vmware-USBArbitrator.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 17:38:08 MyKali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator..
```

Some syslog messages for the wired interface (eth0): I also tried changing managed to false in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
Sep  2 15:50:58 MyKali kernel: [  445.646621] r8169 0000:03:00.1 eth0: link down
Sep  2 15:50:58 MyKali NetworkManager[601]: <info>  [1535892658.1157] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali systemd[1]: Started ifup for eth0.
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali dhclient[535]: Listening on LPF/eth0/2c:4d:54:2f:f7:7d
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali sh[497]: Listening on LPF/eth0/2c:4d:54:2f:f7:7d
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali sh[497]: Sending on   LPF/eth0/2c:4d:54:2f:f7:7d
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali sh[497]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali dhclient[535]: Sending on   LPF/eth0/2c:4d:54:2f:f7:7d
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali dhclient[535]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali kernel: [    1.385057] r8169 0000:03:00.1 eth0: RTL8411 at 0x        (ptrval), 2c:4d:54:2f:f7:7d, XID 1c800800 IRQ 125
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali kernel: [    1.385059] r8169 0000:03:00.1 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali kernel: [    3.602894] r8169 0000:03:00.1 eth0: link down
Sep  2 15:51:29 MyKali kernel: [    3.604726] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0341] guessed connection type (eth0) = 802-3-ethernet
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0341] update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:eth0, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (eth0), uuid: 681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4-687ed5bae28e
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0342] adding eth0 to connections
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0343] adding iface eth0 to eni_ifaces
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0347] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.1/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0694] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Sep  2 15:51:31 MyKali NetworkManager[640]: <info>  [1535892691.0700] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
```

I would really like to not have to unplug the cable in order to log in. Please let me know if I should look at some other log files in order to troubleshoot the issue.