# Can't login to user kali

Tags: login, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux a month ago. It was good until today.

When I submit username and password the box disappears and reappears again asking about username and password. It shows no error. I just can't login.

I don't wanna reinstall it.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. I am in my Kali Virtual Machine now.  At the login screen, there is (should be) a 3-bar icon top right. Click on that (Session Manager). Try changing sessions and see if you can log in with the default Login session.

Comment: This appears to be serious bug in Kali.  I built a test V2020 machine, just did a full upgrade and can no longer log in. I am looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** log in.

Shut down, start up, and then at the login prompt, press:

Ctrl - Alt - F1

This should bring you to a text login prompt. Login as you.

Now I did a " sudo apt-get autoremove  " which removed a bunch of updates and then  "  sudo reboot  "

Upon restart from the above, I could log in normally and I am in my Kali V2020 machine now.

Look through this SU article for assistance.  One of the first ideas was sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade and then sudo reboot.

[Can't login in Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/987969/cant-login-in-kali-linux)